# How can I extract a value from a groupby and store it for later operation?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

After I've done a groupBy, I want to store a value so I can multiply it later.

The type of the groupBy result is 'object' so I can't operate on it.

I've tried creating a dataframe from the groupBy.

# create the df

```
total = df.groupby(['columnName_1'])['columnName_2'].sum().astype('int').map('{:,}'.format) # as I get a very large number, I clean its format for readability

total = total.add_suffix('_global').reset_index()
```

# as it is a sum, I get only one value, the one I want to multiply by another value later.

*I'd like to know now if I can store this value without having to create a dataframe.*

Thanks!

Comment: can you create an example input and output dataframe so we can replicate this?

Comment: To what @anky_91 said: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example